# CKEditor 5, Funcion Editar muestra "Texto Plano"

Tags: laravel-8, ckeditor

estoy haciendo un formulario, donde guardo un texto con CKEditor 5, este funciona bien (aunque aparece arriba Introduce tu titulo y abajo para escribir el contenido).. pero al momento de usar el formulario que edita me aparece arriba "Introduce tu titulo" y abajo en gris un cuadro de "Texto Plano"

mi text area:

```
<textarea id="report" name="report" rows="10" cols="80">
                    @php
                      echo htmlspecialchars_decode($data->report);
                    @endphp
                  </textarea>
```

y este es mi javascript:

```
      watchdog
        .create( document.querySelector( '#report' ), {
        toolbar: {
          items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            '|',
            'outdent',
            'indent',
            '|',
            'imageUpload',
            'blockQuote',
            'insertTable',
            'mediaEmbed',
            'undo',
            'redo',
            'textPartLanguage',
            'todoList',
            'underline',
            'alignment',
            'code',
            'codeBlock',
            'findAndReplace',
            'fontBackgroundColor',
            'fontColor',
            'fontFamily',
            'highlight',
            'fontSize',
            'horizontalLine',
            'htmlEmbed',
            'imageInsert',
            'pageBreak',
            'removeFormat',
            'sourceEditing',
            'specialCharacters',
            'restrictedEditingException',
            'strikethrough',
            'subscript',
            'superscript'
          ]
        },
        language: 'es',
        image: {
          toolbar: [
            'imageTextAlternative',
            'imageStyle:inline',
            'imageStyle:block',
            'imageStyle:side',
            'linkImage'
          ]
        },
        table: {
          contentToolbar: [
            'tableColumn',
            'tableRow',
            'mergeTableCells',
            'tableCellProperties',
            'tableProperties'
          ]
        },
          licenseKey: '',
```

Lo que necesito quitar es... esa parte que dice "Introduce tu titulo, y por otro lado, que en el editor se muestre lo que tengo en la base de datos, con su correspondiente formato, negritas etc.

Alguien sabría como hacer estas 2 cositas?

Answer (score 0):

Para la primera parte de la pregunta, en el `textarea` coloca un atributo llamado `utext` y le agregas lo que tienes en la base de datos.

No sé una respuesta para la segunda parte.